# Use a filter on an array of values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrays, google-sheets-filter

I want to create a spreadsheet which has an array of values split over 1 or more columns. I can do this successfully with the following formula:

```
={"Picard","Q","Data"}
```

This puts each of these values in 3 adjacent cells, which is exactly what I want.

However, next I want to be able to create a filter which can filter the rows based on the value being present in any of these cells. In the above example I can create a filter on the first column, but the filter options only show the value "Picard".

Here's a link to an example spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k9qo3fa0xpFIh31yTSn1odxJcNZ-uxegYRecxfCwPJ4/edit?usp=sharing

Is what I'm trying to do possible, or should I move to a more full featured database?

Answer (score 1):

This is what is shown in the linked spreadsheet

[image]

Please note that each column includes a dropdown button. That is the way that Filter/Filter views work on Google Sheets.

If you want that the filter shows all the values in the array, you should change the shape of the array from 3 columns 1 row to 1 column 3 rows as follows

```
={"Picard";"Q";"Data"}
```

[image]

If you want to keep the original array shape, then you will have to use another method to filter your array, like using functions (i.e. QUERY, FILTER)

Comment: Thanks, that's handy but that doesn't work when you have multiple rows. I get the error "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B3.". Is there any way around that, or do you recommend I move to your function suggestion. (P.S. my example has been updated).

Comment: @IanNewson Insted of changing your example, you should create a new one otherwise it becomes unhelpful for this question, also you should create a new question for your follow-up question.